# Do I need 6 months left on my US passport to travel to Mexico?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-citizens, mexico

I am traveling to Mexico from U.S. in April 18, 2018 and returning to U.S. from Mexico May 3, 2018.  Question is upon my return my passport will expire July 18, 2018.  Is that ok?  Or does it need to expire 6 months from the return date?

Comment: @phoog why did you roll back my edit? This two word title is not helpful at all

Comment: @phoog Irrelevant in this case

Comment: @phoog it was tagged us-citizens. It's rather an edge case to think a US citizen is going to be traveling on another country's passport and not mention it.

Comment: @KateGregory sorry, I did not notice the tag.

Answer (score 5):

No. This is a rule applied by some countries but not Mexico.

The official requirement page for Americans is [here](http://www.sectur.gob.mx/guia-de-viaje/visa/) (in Spanish). There is no mention of a minimum validity. This matches my experience as a Canadian too which you can see is listed along with US citizens on the linked page (meaning the same rules apply).

In the [US Government page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Mexico.html) you can see it also says that the passport must be valid at the *time of entry*.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airport check-in staff:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid **on arrival**.

This goes for any foreign nationality.

So yes, your passport will be acceptable.